# How do you build and deploy to an older version of android for ionic / cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Using Ionic 1.0.0 beta-8

After creating a new app, I built and deployed it to a Nexus 5 emulator and it worked fine. But when I tried to debug it on my Android 2.2 phone, I got this error:

```
....
-post-build:
     [move] Moving 1 file to /home/admin/code/projects/myapp/ionic/platforms/android/ant-build
     [move] Moving 1 file to /home/admin/code/projects/myapp/ionic/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 6 seconds
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device 'I8972b56ddac'.
Using apk: /home/admin/code/projects/myapp/ionic/platforms/android/ant-build/HelloCordova-debug-unaligned.apk
Installing app on device...

/home/admin/code/projects/myapp/ionic/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/HelloCordova-debug-unaligned.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Error: /home/admin/code/projects/myapp/ionic/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
ERROR: Unable to run app on platform android. Please see console for more info.
Exiting.
```

How do I make the build work in ionic/cordova for android 4.x.x phones as well as android 2.2 phones?

Comment: any reason why this is downvoted? what am i missing?

Comment: I disagree with the down votes. I think this is a worthy and important question particularly as cheap smart phones have flooded the market this last year with many running 2.3 .  In 2015, this is NOT an out of date question.

Answer (score 15):

this question is similar to yours.
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135185/how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers/27138144#27138144)

go to your AndroidManifest.xml, find these to control your sdk buildversion.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="XX"> // value is the API LEVEL
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="XX">
```

*targetSdk = tell phonegap which android build version to use, 
 *MinSdk is to limit user who want to download it. 
check the API LEVEL of android build [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html).

**In Your case:** for android 2.2, use value= 8(API level 8)

```
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8"> //android 2.2
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="17"> //android 4.2
```

NOTE: I doubt android 2.2(API level 8) can run API level 17(android 4.2).

Comment: I'm confused in which AndroidManifest.xml file to change ?

Comment: go to platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ionic Platform notes](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html), Ionic targets iPhone and Android devices (currently). It also support iOS 6+, and Android 4.0+ (though 2.3 should work). However, since there are a lot of different Android devices, it's possible certain ones might not work. Ionic did not guaranty for Android 2.3 hence Android 2.2 will be out of scope.

Hence, I think that is the reason why you are having challenges.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, Google back-ported features from Honeycomb and again from later versions of Android into a "compatibility" library. You might be able to install that and get your app working on older versions of Android. You would need to update your Android SDK and install this library.

See [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) docs.

If you're using Ionic, you could add a hook script that copies the library into your project when  you add Android as a platform or start a build.

Answer (score 0):

Change value of `"android-minSdkVersion"` in `config.xml` of your ionic project. It should look like below:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that cdvCompileSdkVersion is used to determine build SDK and NOT targetSdkVersion as one would use in native android apps.