# Ionic splash scree doesn't show up (not even with basic blank app)

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I tried to build several apps for android and i can't get the splash screen working..

I even changed a few different images and it never shows.

I think maybe my android OS is too old (4.1.2). How to build an ionic app for android 4.0 minimum?
How can i know for which platform ionic builds this app?

i just use basic commands:

```
ionic start Beta blank

ionic platform android

ionic build android
```

and then i just install the app on my phone and everything is OK except splashscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did u add this plugin?

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Try to add this on the config.xml file aswell:

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

and build via these commands:

```
ionic build android
ionic run android
```

Comment: still the same....it takes exactly 3 seconds to get into app but splashscreen is white....some more ideas? i found that i build app for Android 5.1.1 maybe thats the problem? i have 4.1.2 on my phone

Comment: Maybe, try to build it on lollipop. Remember the resources files must be exactly same. Here is a work around: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/splashscreen-on-android-doesnt-work-only-showing-white-screen-for-2-seconds/15604/31

Comment: How to build for lollipop?? what is the command? i think i read something "mind" and then the version and now i can't find it

Comment: if I remember correctly, you need to change the minsdk, targetsdk in the android manifest xml file.

Comment: possible same question as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522921/how-do-you-build-and-deploy-to-an-older-version-of-android-for-ionic-cordova