# How can we set an android app to be compatible with differnet android platforms?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Recently I have developed an android application. My first setting during creating the project in the first stages was for android with API level 21. Now I need to use this app in an older or newer version of Android. But it is "Unfortunately has Stopped". I have also used the following solution, but it did not work: [How do you build and deploy to an older version of android for ionic / cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522921/how-do-you-build-and-deploy-to-an-older-version-of-android-for-ionic-cordova) 
The API levels which I intend to use is between 17 and 23. What is your suggestion to meet this frustrating problem? Thank you so much. 
The crash log is as follows:

```
unable to resolve virtual method 232: Landroid/app/Application;.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
unable to resolve interface method 16032: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
```

Comment: it's like a trade off - you wanna new feature then you have to raise your min sdk to some level (not every time ) so better thing is try docs , read about the feature which causing the problem , look for alternative plus better to post your crash logs too

Comment: You're right. The crash logs is added.

Comment: I don't know about Cordova, but a huge part of newest features in Android is also available for older versions using the Support library

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. I tried some solutions but I could not resolve it.
Solutions were:

1. [Android Studio E/dalvikvm: Could not find class... referenced from method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816684/android-studio-e-dalvikvm-could-not-find-class-referenced-from-method)
2. [Android studio many error: Could not find class 'android.XXX'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998266/android-studio-many-error-could-not-find-class-android-xxx#38666791)